# Character date 31.03.2001 to numerical, SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable that was entered as 31.01.2002 for all entries, and is a character. I would like to put it in numerical form with date9. .

I have tried the below:

```
date=input(oldway, 10.);

date=input(oldway, date9.);
put date=ddmmyy10.;

date=input(compress(oldway,'.'),10.);

date = INPUT(compress(oldway),date9.); 
format date date9.;
run;
```

I have also tried combinations of the above and to no avail.

Any ideas for forward motion?

Kind Regards!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't input your date using the `date9.` informat as your string variable isn't in that format. You can use `ddmmyy10.`, though, and that also takes care of the `.` characters.

```
data have;
input old $10.;
cards;
31.01.2014
28.02.2014
01.01.2015
;
run;

data want;
set have;
new = input(old, ddmmyy10.);
format new date9.;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have tried the above recommended but am getting back 2 variables and one observation. The variables are old and new, but good news is the format is spot on! What would I need to do to apply the format to the rest of the observations in the dataset? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
data _null_;
date ="31.01.2014";
date=compress(date,".");

new_date=input(date,ddmmyy8.);
format new_date date9.;
put new_date;
run;
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)